# How do I parse a JSON which contains an array inside a json Object without a arrayName

Tags: swift, swift3

I get a JSON array like this

```
[
{
"accNo":"8567856",
"ifscCode":"YESB000001"
},
{
"accNo":"85678556786",
"ifscCode":"YESB000001"
}
]
```

I get an array with no arrayName in json.
I tried to parse this JSON in swift 3 with type casting it to get the values in all array(using as? NSArray, NSDictionary, [Array -String,AnyObject-],etc).But it all failed. Is there a way in swift to get array values

Comment: Please read the JSON carefully. It's very easy: `[]` is array, `{}` is dictionary, so the JSON is clearly an array of dictionaries with `String` keys and `String` values (`[[String:String]]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) but here's your answer using Foundation.

**Swift 4:**

```
let str = """
[
{
"accNo":"8567856",
"ifscCode":"YESB000001"
},
{
"accNo":"85678556786",
"ifscCode":"YESB000001"
}
]
"""

let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!

do {

    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:String]]

    for item in json! {

        if let accNo = item["accNo"] {
            print(accNo)
        }

        if let ifscCode = item["ifscCode"] {
            print(ifscCode)
        }
    }

} catch {
    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: my bad, fixed it!

Comment: made the necessary changes 

Comment: why are you using for loop to print? Isn't the dictioanary already implement CustomStringConvertible and will print these values in a single statement?

Comment: OP wanted to parse individual values. print is just a way to show you can retrieve them like this

Comment: Alternately, guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:String]] else { /* handle error */ return}

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) to convert data to an array of Dictionary of Strings, `[[String:String]]`.

```
let str = """
[
{
"accNo":"8567856",
"ifscCode":"YESB000001"
},
{
"accNo":"85678556786",
"ifscCode":"YESB000001"
}
]
"""
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [[String:String]]
print(json) // [["accNo": "8567856", "ifscCode": "YESB000001"], ["accNo": "85678556786", "ifscCode": "YESB000001"]]
```